# Connecting different AudioKit Effects in array

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, audiokit

I have an array of AudioKit effect to have the flexibility to add/remove or change the order of them, storing them as AKNode

```
var effects : [AKNode] = []

effects.append(AKCompressor())
effects.append(AKDelay())
effects.append(AKAutoWah())
... ...
```

The problem is doing the connections:

```
effects[0].connect(to: effects[1])
```

It doesn't work : Cannot invoke 'connect' with an argument list of type '(to: AKNode)'

Maybe I should store other class than AKNode. What's the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array of AKInputs.  The [connection functions](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/AKConnection.swift) use the [AKInput](http://audiokit.io/docs/Protocols/AKInput.html) and [AKOutput](http://audiokit.io/docs/Protocols/AKOutput.html) protocols.  AKInput inherits from AKOutput so they're outputs too.